# Can a numpy image (W, H) with intensity be converted to rgb format (W, H, 3) and same display result as in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can a numpy image (W, H) with intensity be converted to rgb format (W, H, 3) and same imshow result?
Eg, a numpy image `img1 = (128,128)` with intensity (not greyscale) => convert it to `img2 = (128,128,3)`. Running `pyplot.imshow(img1)` and `pyplot.imshow(img2)` can get the same display result.

Comment: very unclear... [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib.imshow` uses `colormaps` behind the scenes, and so can you.

1. Get the appropriate color map from `matplotlib.colormaps` (use "viridis" if you aren't sure)
2. Apply that to your input array

Here is the [Colormap documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) in case you want to learn more.

Here is some sample code that shows how to accomplish it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)

img1 = rng.random(size=(128, 128))
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()

img2 = mpl.colormaps['viridis'](img1)
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

If the original image is grayscale (meaning it doesn't contain color channel information), converting it to RGB won't add meaningful color differences between the channels. In a grayscale image, all three channels (RGB) have the same values. When you convert it to RGB, all channels will be identical, and the image will still appear grayscale.

Here's the code example:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Change the greyscale path according to the image path you want.
Greyscale = Image.open("d:/Greyscale.jpeg")
GreyscaleRGB = Greyscale.convert("RGB")
np_image = np.array(GreyscaleRGB)

plt.imshow(np_image, cmap="virdis")
plt.axis(False)
plt.show()
print(np_image.shape)
```

The code above will plot the image and the image will still appear as a grayscale even if you already turn the format into RGB (W,H,3)

Print output example will be

> (1696, 2400, 3)

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't appear to yield the same results as just `imshow`-ing the (W, H, 1) numpy array.

Comment: OP said *"intensity (not greyscale)"*. OP's question is unclear. -- @BitsAreNumbersToo matplotlib may stretch the value range too.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Agreed on the slightly confusing question. You might be right about the stretching, it appears as though it may be ever so slightly differently coloured, feel free to suggest an edit that corrects that.